# How to show Snackbar on scrolling up and dismiss on scrolling down in Recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, material-design, android-snackbar, snackbar

I'm trying to implement a Snackbar which will show and dismiss when user scroll on a RecyclerView. This is the .xml file for the view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/activityFriendsList">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/friendsRecyclerView"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is also the function which is supposed to do the work

```
Snackbar snackbar;


 recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            snackbar = Snackbar.make(activity, "Add new friend", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
            snackbar.show();
            if (dy > 0) {
                Log.i("Info", "Scrolling up");
                if(snackBarIsShowing) {
                    snackBarIsShowing = false;
                }
            }
            if (dy < 0){
                Log.i("Info", "Scrolling down");
                if(!snackBarIsShowing) {
                    snackBarIsShowing = true;
                }
            }

            if (snackBarIsShowing) {
                Log.i("Info", "Create new");
                snackbar.dismiss();
            } else {
                Log.i("Info", "Dismiss the old one");

            }
        }

    });
```

What I think that the problem could be is that right now I'm not trying to dismiss the right snack bar. 
Any idea how I can overcome this problem.

Comment: Why you are not using `snackbar.show()` in else ?

Comment: I place is there just to check if dismiss works when I scroll up.

Comment: But your code looks like well, You just have to add `snackbar.show` in else to make it visible .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this, I have tested it and it is working properly.

```
  RecyclerAdapter adapter;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
private Snackbar snackbar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    snackbar = Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "should disappear when scrolling!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(myList);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public final void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            if (!recyclerView.canScrollVertically(-1)) {

                if (!snackbar.isShown())
                    snackbar.show();

            } else if (!recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1)) {
                if (snackbar.isShown())
                    snackbar.dismiss();
            }
            if (dy < 0) {
                if (!snackbar.isShown())
                    snackbar.show();
            } else if (dy > 0) {
                if (snackbar.isShown())
                    snackbar.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**Note:** `canScrollVertically(int direction)`
`direction` int: Negative to check scrolling up, positive to check scrolling down. see documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#canScrollVertically)

Comment: Can you please explain what this code is exactly doing ?

Comment: Where should I initialize the snackbar inside the .addOnScrollListener or outside.

`snackbar = Snackbar.make(activity, "Add new friend", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);`

Comment: In your case did you used Coordinator Layout? 
Also I just found out that using your method dismiss doesn't work also.

Comment: yes, I am using coordinatorLayout. and it's working like a charm.do you use CoordinaorLayout?

Comment: I'm trying to implement this in a Fragment and when i initialize it outside the function it says *No suitable parent found from the given view.* 
`final View activity = view.findViewById(R.id.activityFriendsList);
 snackbar = Snackbar.make(activity, "Add new friend", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);`

Comment: you should tie your snackbar to your parent container in this case. we get this parent using this way `view.findViewById(android.R.id.content)`.as in my answer.

Comment: Yeah I just gave it the id from the Coordinatior Layout and worked as I wanted thanks a lot. I already approved this answer.